# Driving flyback transformer with variable frequency

Tags: transformer, mosfet-driver, flyback, resonance, self-resonant-frequency

Is it good idea/practice to drive a flyback transformer using two MOSFETs, similar to common ZVS drivers, but instead by controlling the gates without depending on resonance and LC tank calculations?

**Since there will be no induction heating coil, or tesla coil at the output, but only the flyback primary coil, does this driver circuit need capacitors at all?**

(*i.e. since this driver doesn't depend on self oscillation of an LC tank, is any caps needed?*)

---

More details:

The suggested driver circuit is:

1. A pulse generator with custom (tunable) frequency signals a MOSFET gate driver.
2. the gate driver switches two MOSFETs properly.
3. Each MOSFET actuates the primary coil of the transformer in a direction. (Opposite of each other). So the final output of the transformer is a zero crossing AC voltage.

This way fine control over frequency and duty cycle is achieved and it's possible to let the transformer core "rest" (i.e lose most of its stored energy to the secondary coil) before the next cycle starts. (Discontinuous Mode)

Comment: A flyback transformer is only defined as such because of it being used in a flyback circuit. Also: you probably wouldn't favour a transformer designed for flyback operation in a non flyback circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka There's many demonstrations of these transformers being drived by ZVS (mazzilli) circuits. My suggested driver is actually more similar to the flyback driver in TV sets (higher frequency, NCM, low duty cycle) than a ZVS designed for induction heating (Sine wave, CM, %50 duty cycle).  I thought by gaining full control over driving wave (its frequency, wave shape and duty cycle) one could reach ultimate efficiency/safety/endurance for the circuit/transformer core.

Comment: If you want the performance of a Baxandall inverter build a Baxandall inverter.